# Set Y offset of Box Collider to zero and cover the whole image

Tags: unity-game-engine

Y Offset of Box Collider 2D is negative. I wanted this to become 0 or positive value.
[image]

Y Offset of Box Collider 2D is zero but the image now halfway. How will I make it 0 but still covering the whole image.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not make much sense to avoid negative values but you could probably change the pivot in sprite import settings

[image: Inspector]

Comment: Yes, this works great! I changed it to Bottom Center.